# how to use ABRecordGetRecordID to fill up a table with contactinformation

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, nsnumber

I have a sqlite database where i store ABRecordGetRecordID's of a contact.
I convert the ABRecordGetRecordID's to an NSNumber to store it in the database:

2014-05-21 14:35:12.122 ProjectMobile[17858:60b] 179962464 <-- this is the kind of number i get when i log the following:

```
#import "HulpViewcontroller.h"
#import "AidTableViewcell.h"
@property UIColor * firstColor;
@property UIColor * secondColor;
@property NSMutableArray *Personen;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation HulpViewController

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.Personen count];
}

- (IBAction)pickPerson:(id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {

    [[peoplePicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    // Create a new person
    NSManagedObject *newPersoon = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Personen" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    NSNumber *id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];
    NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    NSLog(@"%d", id);
    [newPersoon setValue: id forKey:@"persoonId"];
    [newPersoon setValue: one forKey:@"importance"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![self.context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }




        [[peoplePicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{

    return NO;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"hulpCell";

    AidTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AidTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    // check if row is odd or even and set color accordingly
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = self.firstColor;
    }else {
        cell.backgroundColor = self.secondColor;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.firstColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:183/255.0f green:80/255.0f blue:23/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.secondColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:179/255.0f green:98/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.Personen = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Man.jpeg", @"Doctor.jpeg", @"Son.jpeg", nil];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Personen"];
    self.personen = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

How can i use the Id i stored in the database to put information of the contacts of those id's in a tableview?

I updated the code. This way it will be easier for you guys to help me out :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could e.g. do something like this:

```
CFErrorRef error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions (NULL, &error);

if (addressBookRef != nil) {
    ABRecordID recordID = yourPersonRecordID; // Assign here your ID
    ABRecordRef nxtABRecordRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (addressBookRef, recordID);
    // Do anything with your record, e.g.
    ABMultiValueRef addressesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(nxtABRecordRef, kABPersonAddressProperty);

    if (addressesRef != nil) {
        for (int index = 0; index < ABMultiValueGetCount(addressesRef); index++) {
            NSDictionary *addressDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressesRef,index);
            // Do something with the persons data
        } // for all addresses

        CFRelease(addressesRef);
    }

    CFRelease(addressBookRef);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not open address book");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
But i'm new to IOS development, i can't figure out what to do with your code. Is there any way i can share my screen with you? 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I am pretty busy. I don't believe it would work with screen sharing. If you tell me what your actual problem is, maybe I can help. I will be online again maybe in 12 hours...

Comment: When the table view is displayed, the table view 1st asks for a cell to display. You assign the cell to be used in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You could e.g. set cell.textlabel.text there to some text taken from the address book. Which contents should be used is defined by indexPath.row. You had to read the corresponding recordID from your database, look up the address book using something like my code above, extract e.g. the person's name, and assign it to the textLabel of the cell.